# How to enable Metadata publishing for WCF service

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, rest, metadata

My config file is below. 
Namespace is not define therefore class is directly added.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="servicebehavior">


      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restbehavior">

      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"></binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>
  <service name ="DataManager"
  behaviorConfiguration ="servicebehavior" >

    <endpoint name ="SOAPEndPoint"
    contract ="IDatamanager"
    binding ="basicHttpBinding"
    address ="soap" />

    <endpoint name ="RESTEndPoint"
    contract ="IDataManagerrest"
    binding ="webHttpBinding"
    address ="rest"
    behaviorConfiguration ="restbehavior"/>

    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
    binding="mexHttpBinding"
    address="mex" />
  </service>

</services>
```

Comment: Looks fine for me, except you're missing the privacy policy. This _might_ be the issue. Look at #4 on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: oops
- abstract class and interface in actual programming 
- polymorphous 
- function overriding with missing key word
- static constructor, static variable 
- which one is call first in polymorphisum scenario (i.e. child class variable or parent class variable)


- DB
- Can we change views (update views), HOW 
- What is  triggers ?
- GO 4 --->insert statement 
- trigger scenario .
scinario : 1. Insert record then 2. update column 1 3. then we have to update column 3 then how